# Couenne option for pyomo

Tags: pyomo, coin-or

I am trying to activate the Couenne option as suggested on online pyomo help, As an example:
opt = SolverFactory('couenne')
opt.options['display_stats']= 'yes'
But I am receiving the following error:

ApplicationError: Solver (asl) did not exit normally

I also check the :
opt.options['couenne.display_stats']= 'yes'

Regards

Comment: was there no stack trace?

Comment: Could you add `tee=True` as an option to the `solve` call and post the solver output?

Comment: I add tee = tree : couenne: Unknown keyword "display_stats"
Unknown keyword "display_stats"
ERROR: Solver (asl) returned non-zero return code (1)
ERROR: See the solver log above for diagnostic information.
  File "E://NonLinearGoalProgramming//BuildGNLP.py", line 94, in <module>
    result_obj = opt.solve(model,logfile="logfile_couenne.log",tee=True,report_timing=True)

  File "C:\Users\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\base\solvers.py", line 596, in solve
    "Solver (%s) did not exit normally" % self.name)

ApplicationError: Solver (asl) did not exit normally